# Display dates as columns using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table like this.

```
------------------------------------
Id | Name | Date  
-----------------------------------
1  | Syam | 2017-05-23 13:53:20.000
2  | Syam | 2017-05-22 13:53:20.000
3  | Syam | NULL
4  | Ram  | 2017-05-23 13:53:20.000
5  | Ram  | 2017-05-21 13:53:20.000
```

I need to find out the users who have submitted their log in 7 days prior to the specified date input by user.
The result will be like this

Input: 2017-05-28 13:53:20.000

```
Id | Name | 05/23/2017 tuesday | 05/22/2017 Monday | 05/21/2017
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  |Syam  | True               | true              | False
2  |Ram   | True               | False             | True
```

Can some one help me to do this. I think pivot can be used for this. But I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Sorry SqlServer

Answer (score 0):

you can use pivot

```
   select pvt.* from 
   (
   select id,name,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, date1) as DayName  from t
   ) as  t1
   PIVOT
   (max(name) for DayName in ([Tuesday],[Monday],[Sunday] )) as pvt -- you can put 7days name here
```